# Regex Extraction for Google Analytics Content Grouping

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm attempting to setup [Content Groupings using Extraction](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2853546?hl=en#extract) within Google Analytics.

I have URL's of the form http://www.ehattons.com/52674/Bachmann_Branchline_37_671_Pack_of_3_14_Ton_tank_wagons_in_Fina_livery_weathered/StockDetail.aspx

I wish to use Regex to say that only in cases where a URL contains /StockDetail.aspx, extract everything before the first underscore, excluding any digits. e.g. 'Bachmann'.

I've managed to source the following regex to return everything before the first underscore

`^[^_]+(?=_)`.

However, that's as far as I can get with my limited understanding. Anyone know what regex will do the trick here?

Many thanks,

Comment: As an alternative, you can try [`^[^_]*/[0-9]+/([^_]*).*/StockDetail[.]aspx`](https://regex101.com/r/tR9nW1/2).

Answer (score 0):

Well you did the halfway.

Think about it this way : you're looking for extracting something followed by a underscore but not following one when the string contain */StockDetail.aspx*. You know that this part of string will always be after your first underscore.

So you start with no underscore before : `[^_]`
Then you create the group you want to match with `([a-zA-Z]*)` (you cannot work with \w since it's including underscore). Your string has to be followed by a underscore so you add `_` after your group. And finnaly somewhere in the url you've got `/StockDetail.aspx`. Your regex should look like this :

```
[^_]([a-zA-Z]*)_.*(?:\/StockDetail\.aspx)
```

[Result](https://regex101.com/r/tG7xV3/1)